# How to Find-Replace Multiple words in One Line using Notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I need to find-replace multiple lines in notepad++. Can someone please write a single line "search and replace" query (regular expression), so that I could replace multiple lines in one go?

I want to remove **< div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;" >**, **< /div >**, **height** and **width** attributes. Moreover I want to replace **s320** with **s600**.

Example Document where I will perform search:

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SLNIctalDjg/UmgAjaUmYNI/AAAAAAACzuw/p5r6y6Yv7jQ/s1600/131.JPG" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" height="256" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SLNIctalDjg/UmgAjaUmYNI/AAAAAAACzuw/p5r6y6Yv7jQ/s320/131.JPG" width="320" /></a></div>
<br /></div>
```

I am looking for a single line search-replace query like, I could do something like;

```
Find: find1|find2|find3|find4
Replace: NOTHING|NOTHING|NOTHING|replace4
```

Looking for help... thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand - do you simply not want to do four find and replaces in a row?  Or are you trying to do a search on text that spans multiple lines in your file?

Comment: Nevermind - just realized you are talking about doing four different find and replaces in one go.  Are there any text editors that allow something like that? It doesn't seem like it'd be that much trouble to do four find and replaces yourself.  If this is something you're doing over and over again, perhaps you can write a program that translates a file that's in one form into another?

Comment: Derek, Actually I had to perform this search-replace query on many text files, I receive those text files one by one via email and then perform search-replace and email them back immediately. If it was like 1 or 2 files, I could have perform search-replace one by one but since I have to do it with multiple files, it is time consuming that is why I asked for a solution. PSXLS has given very useful solution and I am now using MACRO to sort out the issue I mentioned in question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** do that using Notepad++'s search and replace.

You will have to apply a regex at least twice. For example:

1. First one:

   - Search:

     ```
     (?:</?div.*?>|width="\d+?"|height="\d+?")
     ```
   - Replace:

     ```
     *nothing*
     ```
2. Second:

   - Search:

     ```
     s320
     ```
   - Replace:

     ```
     s600
     ```

**BUT** you can record a Macro with those two replacements. Go to "Macro" > "Start Recording" menu, apply those two search and replace regular expressions, press "Stop Recording", then "Save Current Recorded Macro", there give it a name, assign a shortcut, and you are done.